# Morphia 0.110 does not find references with string id

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

We are working with mongodb/morphia since the early versions of morphia. So we always used a string as id-Field in our persistent objects:

```
  @Id
  private String id;

  public PersistentEntity() {
      id = new ObjectId().toHexString();
  }
```

Up to Version 0.108 of morphia that was fine. Since morphia 0.110 however, references to objects with id as outlined above are not found any longer. The error shown is:

```
Mrz 10, 2015 9:49:35 AM org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ReferenceMapper$1
eval WARNUNG: Null reference found when retrieving value for
<classname>
```

Currently our systems run with mongodb 2.6.8, java-driver 2.13.0 and morphia 0.108.

So how do we migrate the existing data on the customer systems? There is no way to change _id Field from String to ObjectId - mongodb does not allow that. Are we stuck with morphia 0.108?

Has anyone solved similar problems?

Comment: String IDs should work fine.  If you post a test case to the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/morphia), I'll take a look at it.  We have multiple tests using Strings, ints, longs, and even custom objects as IDs and they're all passing.  If I can see what you're doing that's different, I can spot your error or more likely I can close that gap in our test coverage.

Comment: There is an example now at [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/Ydwl-iUXurA. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple datastores in the same app? There was a change in that area and we've had similar issues with the same version.

There will be a fix in 1.0-rc, which should be the next release.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why morphia failed to find references in some cases: We use multiple databases. However: release morphia-1.0.0-rc0 does not solve the problem. I finally figured out what you have to do: When you create your datastore do it as follows: `Mapper mapper = new Mapper(dsProvider); ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoServer, mapper, dbName);` Your mapper is constructed with your own implementation of a  DataStoreProvider, because the DefaultDatastoreProvider stores all DataStores in just one place. Or you can use morphias SingleDatastoreProvider. Hope that will help.